# OR operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions or to Integer or Long expressions?

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I have the following code:

```
public class Testcode {



private static final Long[] P = new Long[18];             

public void setKey( string key )    

{    

integer i, j, k;    

long data;    

integer N = 16;    

string[] keytemp = new string[]{}; keytemp.add(key);



// Initialize P and S.    

for ( i = 0; i < N + 2; ++i ){        

P[i] = Pinit[i];        

}              

// XOR the key into P.    

j = 0;    

for ( i = 0; i < N + 2; ++i )        

{        

data = 0;        

for ( k = 0; k < 4; ++k )        

{       

data = ( data << 8 ) | keytemp[j];        

++j;        

}        

P[i] ^= data;        

}              

}   



private static final long[] Pinit = new Long[] {       

604135516L,   2242044355L,  320440478L ,  57401183L,        

2732047618L,  698298832L,   137296536L ,  3964563569L,        

1163258022L,  954160567L,   3193502383L,  887688400L,        

3234508543L,  3380367581L,  1065660069L,  3041631479L,        

2420952273L,  2306437331L       

};      

}
```

im getting the following error:

Error: Compile Error: OR operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions or to Integer or Long expressions at line 36 column 18

which is in this line:

```
   data = ( data << 8 ) | keytemp[j];
```

Is there another way to write this line of code?

Thanks

Comment: `keytemp` is a string array. Why are you trying to perform a bitwise `or` with a string as one of the operands?

Comment: Well in java I can declare the string key as byte and this line of code works fine, but APEX doesn't have byte variables. Do you know another way to do this?

Comment: In general you shouldn't be using strings to represent byte arrays, even in Java. That's what byte arrays are for. The closest you'll probably get in apex is to use a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the keytemp array contains strings of length 1 since Apex doesn't have a Character primitive.  You'll have to convert the first character of each string to an integer and then perform the OR.

Unfortunately Apex doesn't appear to have a built-in way of getting the ASCII value of a single-character String. You may have to write your own convertor function. Here are some people with the same issue with some proposed solutions:

[Discussion of how to convert strings to ASCII values](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Convert-a-string-to-ASCII-values/td-p/67664)

Comment: well I used one of the codes in the link you gave, and I don't have an error, but I still havn't looked at the result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

No loops except for the initial priming of the array ... And later we have to get each character separately but looks like your algorithm needs 1-char long strings anyway?

```
List<Integer> ints = new List<Integer>();
for(Integer i =0; i < 256; ++i){
    ints.add(i);
}
String allAscii = String.fromCharArray(ints);

// System.debug(allAscii);  // funny result if you really want to start from 0x00 character
System.debug(allAscii.substring(1));    // for demo purposes we'll show only from 0x01 though

String text = 'Hi StackOverflow.com!';
for(Integer i =0; i < text.length(); ++i){
    String oneChar = text.mid(i, 1);
    System.debug(oneChar + ' => ' + allAscii.indexOf(oneChar));
}
```

Output:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{&#124;}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ

H => 72
i => 105
  => 32
S => 83
t => 116
a => 97
c => 99
k => 107
O => 79
v => 118
e => 101
r => 114
f => 102
l => 108
o => 111
w => 119
. => 46
c => 99
o => 111
m => 109
! => 33
```

Looks good to me (space is # 32 etc).

Could be further optimized to a linear search if you'd build a `Map<String, Integer>` instead of indexOf but I'd say it's good enough?